# PHP variable not loading more than once?

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable that contains post data:

```
$ttransid = $_POST["t_transid"];
```

I then connect to a database and pull info from the row that corresponds with `$ttransid`.
This works fine.

A paypal transaction is then made, if the payment is successful the database is updated with the payment info - This works.

Now my code tries to update the database and remove stock based on the original `$ttransid` variable at the beginning.

```
 $querysub = "UPDATE ibn_table SET iname = iname - 1 WHERE itransaction_id='$ttransid'";
        if(!mysql_query($querysub))
        {
            //mysql error..!
        }
```

The database is updated, but only where `itransaction_id` is blank, suggesting `$ttransid` is empty. Although it was called and used correctly at the beginning of the code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you actually tried seeing what `$ttransid` (and `$_POST` for that matter) contains? Your question is suggesting you have not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because next time your page is hit, the `$_POST` is empty so there is no `$_POST["t_transid"]`. So when you assign

```
 $ttransid = $_POST["t_transid"];
```

It gets empty and update empty string. I suggest you to save that post variable value in your database or in session so you can use that latter.

Comment: Thats the one. I failed to take in to account the redirect to paypal. I should be able to pass the data to paypal and retrieve it again in the call back. Thanks.

Comment: Well I just got it to work based on that. So maybe I owe you a cookie as well. :D

Comment: @Chris'Pig'Hill hahahah. Its my pleasure :D

Answer (score 0):

At starting point before going to the paypal payment page just keep the $transid [Availabe in POST data] in to the session then after payment success, update db with session transid.

After this process just destroy the transid from the session.

Sure it will work.